# Swift SKAction unexpected behavior with node.position.x

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3, skaction

I defined several SKActions such as the ones below to move various nodes to a given location. I defined the destination X coordinate as platform.position.x and the destination Y coordinate as platform.position.y - 900. The expected behavior is that the nodes will move downward by 900, but remain in the same x position. Instead, the nodes move downward at an angle, towards each other culminating at the center before finally disappearing off screen. I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let platform1 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.yellow, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 60))

    platform1.xScale = 0.8
    platform1.yScale = 0.8
    platform1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: platform1.size.width, height: platform1.size.width / 6))

    platform1.position = CGPoint(x: -170, y: -270)
    platform1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
    platform1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
    platform1.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    platform1.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    platform1.physicsBody?.friction = 0

    addChild(platform1)


    let platform1GlideOff = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: platform1.position.x, y: platform1.position.y - 900), duration: TimeInterval(5))

    var firstActionplatform1 = SKAction.run({
        platform1.run(platform1GlideOff)
    })

        let platform2 = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 60))

        platform2.xScale = 0.8
        platform2.yScale = 0.8
        platform2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: platform2.size.width, height: platform2.size.width / 6))

        platform2.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: -270)
        platform2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        platform2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        platform2.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
        platform2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        platform2.physicsBody?.friction = 0

        addChild(platform2)


        let platform2GlideOff = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: platform1.position.x, y: platform1.position.y - 900), duration: TimeInterval(5))

        var firstActionplatform2 = SKAction.run({
            platform2.run(platform2GlideOff)
        })


    var sequence = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1), firstActionplatform1, firstActionplatform2])

    run(sequence)
    }
}
```

Comment: It must be something outside of the code that you have posted. We'll need some more code to figure this out. As is the code you have posted works exactly as would be expected I copy and pasted into code and it works.

Comment: @RonMyschuk I've updated the code with 2 nodes to demonstrate

Comment: x position is not the same for both platforms thus your issue

Comment: looks like a copy and paste fail.  Platform 2 is using platform 1 position on the Glideoff

Comment: Oh! I should have seen that! Thanks!